# Java stream - collect, transform and collect

Tags: java, java-stream, java-11

I would like to get the values of the map and find the min value and construct a new CodesWithMinValue instance for each entry of the map. I want this using Java 11 streams, I can achieve this using multiple streams in more than one line(one for min value and one for transformation). is it possible to achieve in a single line using java 11 streams and collectors?
Thank you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> codesMap = getMockedCodesFromUpstream();
        var minValue = Collections.min(codesMap.values());
        var resultList = codesMap.entrySet().stream()
                .map(e -> new CodesWithMinValue(e.getKey(), e.getValue(), minValue))
                .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList());

        //is it possible to combine above three lines using stream and collectors API, 
       //and also can't call getMockedCodesFromUpstream() more than once. getMockedCodesFromUpstream() is a mocked implementation for testing.
        //TODO: combine above three lines into a single line if possible
        System.out.println(resultList);
    }
    
    private static Map<String, Integer> getMockedCodesFromUpstream(){
        Map<String, Integer> codesMap = new HashMap<>();
        codesMap.put("CDXKF", 44);
        codesMap.put("GFDFS", 13);
        codesMap.put("KUSSS", 10);
        codesMap.put("EWSNK", 52);
        codesMap.put("IOLHF", 21);
        return codesMap;
    }

    private static class CodesWithMinValue{
        public final String code;
        public final int value;
        public final int minValue;

        public CodesWithMinValue(String code, int value, int minValue) {
            this.code = code;
            this.value = value;
            this.minValue = minValue;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "CodesWithMinValue{" +
                    "code='" + code + '\'' +
                    ", value=" + value +
                    ", minValue=" + minValue +
                    '}';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel this can be simplified by refactoring and hiding away pieces of data rather than overengineering with Collectors.

```
  private static BiFunction<Map<String, Integer>, Integer, List<MyNode>> getListOfMyNodeWithMinValue =
      (map, minValue) ->
          map.entrySet().stream()
              .map(entry -> new MyNode(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), minValue))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());

  public static Function<Map<String, Integer>, List<MyNode>> getMyNodes =
      map -> getListOfMyNodeWithMinValue.apply(map, Collections.min(map.values()));
```

This can be used thereafter as `MyNode.getMyNodes.apply(inputMap)`.

Ignore my naming conventions. Just typed in whatever I felt. Hope you got the idea.